# Perl apply partial match regex on a line in long text file using hash key

Tags: regex, perl, file-io, hash

**Input1**: I have a chemicalnames hash.These names are short names and are the keys to hash.
**Input2**: I have a text book (I mean a very long text file) where above shortnames appear in full.

**Task**: Where ever the name appears in full in text file , if the next line is with "" then I have to replace this "" with relevant hash value description.            $hash{key}{description}.

**Example**: if hash **key = Y** then it might appear in text file as either
X.Y.Z or just X.YZ or XYZ or XY2 or X_Y_Z02 .Its unpredictable but it appears somewhere in the middle or end.
**That means the text file name is a partial match to hash key name.**

**My Trails:** I tried keeping full file into array then tried to find where empty "" appears .Once it appear I do regex compare on previous line with hash key.But this doesnot work :( .Also the process is too slow.I have tried different kind of techniques with experts help but failed to reduce speed with other methods.Please help

My program is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;



my $file = "Chemicalbook.txt"; #In text file full name might appear as    Dihydrogen.monoxide.hoax_C 
my $previous_line = "";

my %hash;

$hash{'monoxide'}{description}   = "accelerates corrosion";
open(my $FILE,'<',$file) or die "Cannot open input file";
open(my $output,'>',"outfile.txt") or die "Cannot open output file";

my @file_in_array = <$FILE>;

foreach my $line (@file_in_array) {
   my $name = $previous_line;
   if($line =~ /""/) {
     foreach my $shortname(keys %hash) 
     {
       if($previous_line =~ /$shortname/) {
         $line = s/""/$hash{$shortname}{description}/;
       }
     }
    }
  $previous_line = $line;   
  print {$output} $line ;   
}

close($FILE);
close($output);
```

Comment: You have not defined `%hash` anywhere.

Comment: Hi actualy my hash is a very big one which is global variable.processed in other function so missed to include it . Thank you

Comment: Very big hash and very big file so its taking very long time for me. Also since the text files full names are not standard once I am unable to use any perl functions like substr... I am not sure if there is a solution for this but found that we can do partial regex on hashs like /$fullname/ ~~ keys  % hash but I am not quite getting the syntax correct.

Comment: Could do with some sample data here I think. But `grep` is probably the tool you're looking for.

Comment: HI I have provided an example above and in description . With that can you please tell me the syntax of using grep please? My data is too large...is there a file upload here?

Comment: I just searched for grep and put it in my code as if grep { /$previous_line/ } keys %hash; but how to know which key is matched :(

Comment: my @key= grep { $prevoius_line =~ /$_/ } keys(%hash);
print $hash{$key[0]};

Comment: if(($key)= grep { $line =~ /$_/ } keys(%hash)) {
print $hash{$key};
}

Comment: Your "too long" problem is unavoidable if you have to loop over all keys over all lines. Please give an example of a few such keys. And please give examples of *actual* text in `Chemicalbook.txt ` that represent each of your  XYZ patterns.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without some of your data, it will be impossible for us to reproduce this problem.

Comment: ok I shall simplify my query. I want to search for a partial match key in a hash in a quickest way.Once found I can exit.                Example:  If I have a  long_name = 'Chromium.trioxideChromic_02acid'   in a string . I want to match it with my key =  trioxide in  a hash , once matched I can exit from hash. Please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

```
my %hash;
my @arr=qw(X.Y.Z  X.YZ  XYZ  XY2 ZZZ Chromium.trioxideChromic_02acid);
$hash{'Y'}='Hello';
$hash{'R'}='Hai';
$hash{'trioxide'}='Testing';

foreach my $line (@arr)
{
        if( my($key)= grep { $line =~ /$_/ } keys(%hash)) {
                print "$line - $hash{$key} \n";
        }
        else {
           print "Unmatched $line\n";
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for response, What is $key ? Is it $_ instead ?

Comment: I did try above suggested code using grep but the problem is it takes too long (for me it takes 2 minutes 48 seconds).I would like to reduce it to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over all keys for each line is hopeless(ly slow). Try replacing the *entire* inner foreach loop with this:

```
while ($previous_line =~ /(\w+)/g)
  {
    if (my $s = $hash{$1})
      {
        $line = $$s{description};
      }
  }
```

It will pick up shortnames as long as they're "standing alone" in the text.

Comment: Its not a standalone name in text file. Thats what is my probelm.otherwise i would have done if exists in hash check